# What difference it will make, if we have uniform extension (.c/.cpp) for all C/C++ files?

Tags: c++, c, file, implementation, header-files

In `C/C++` project, *mostly* the file can be of either types `.h` or `.c`/`.cpp`. Apart from their naming difference such as header and implementation files; is there any **functionality difference ?**

In other words: if in a working `C/C++` project **what difference it makes** if we change all files with `.c` or `.cpp` extension ?

[Note: We can also have `#include` guards for `.c/.cpp` files. We can skip their compilation if they are observed as headers.]

**Edit**:
Debate is not intended for this as I don't have any solid use case. Rather I wanted to know, that allowing to give `.h`,`.hxx`,`.i` extensions are just a facility or a rule. e.g. One functionality difference I see is that `.cxx` files can have their likable object files.

Comment: `gcc -c *.cpp` would no longer work as expected.  Not sure if that matters to you.

Comment: I'd interested to read what advantage you think this can bring to your project. I assume you have a problem you need to solve or have identified other benefits for using the approach. I can only imagine negative outcomes. Please tell us:-) ! Good luck!

Comment: @cHao, even though the content of `.cpp` and `.h` are same, still it will not work ? I tried writing a very small test program, but didn't give any problem.

Comment: It's worth noting that tools like `make` often have built-in rules for .cpp/.c files.

Comment: It *might* work.  As long as the file's code is valid syntax for the extension you chose (or you used the right compiler options), it should compile...particularly if you're compiling yourself and not using `make`.  But it'd end up generating an object file, and only half of your object files (read: none of your headers-as-C++-files) would be of any use at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What difference does it make? The compiler is perfectly happy about it. To it, it's just files.

But to you? You makes a lot of difference:

- you're no longer able to immediately figure out which one is the header and which one is the implementation;
- you can no longer give header and implementation the same name;

Comment: Well naturally where you used to have foo.h and foo.cpp, you would now have foo.cpp twice, which can't be allowed, so you can have a rule, such as that the former headers can be named like foo.h.cpp, which satisfies all the possible needs!!

Comment: No functional difference. All file extensions are for humans. Of course, many applications make assumptions based on file extensions, gcc is one example.

Comment: Also, the Visual C++ compiler will by default [either compile the file as C or C++ depending on the file extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx) unless you override that behavior with compiler switches.

Comment: @Chris @In silico That only matters if you change C++ files to `.c` or C files to `.cpp`. The question was about changing headers `.h` to either `.c` or `.cpp`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using gcc, and you try and compile a bunch of C++ files labled with a .c extension, it's going to try and compile your file as-if it were a C-language file, which is going to create a ton of errors.

There's also project sanity as well ... this is why many times you'll see projects actually label C++ headers as .hpp rather than just .h so that it's easier to create a distinction between C-language source-code and headers, and C++ source-code and headers.

Comment: "If you are using gcc" ... without the proper flags set.

Answer (score 1):

Header files generally must not be compiled directly but instead #included in a file that is directly compiled. By giving these two groups of files their own extension it makes it a lot easier to determine which to compile.

Make and IDE's and other tools normally expect the conventions of .c/.cpp for source and h/hpp for header. Compiler normally goes a step further and defaults to C compilation for .c and c++ compilation for .cpp

Hence, a bad idea to give your headers the same extension as the the source files.